# How do I prevent jquery validation from highlighting my fields when I unhide them?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, expressiveannotations

On my forms I have numerous optional fields that are only needed if a prior checkbox or radio button value is supplied. To keep the form clean I'm hiding those additional fields until they're needed.

The issue I'm having is when those fields are unhidden they're being highlighted as if they had an error, most likely because they're marked as conditionally required. Is there any way to prevent this from happening so the validation only happens on submit?

I'm using [ExpressiveAnnotations](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations) and unobtrusive validation is wiring everything up. My jquery validation config is:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: (element) => {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: element => {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    }
});
```

To hide or show the extra fields I've wrapped them in a `div` and toggle the visibility with a class called `hidden`.

Comment: [How to control frequency of dependent fields validation?](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations#how-to-control-frequency-of-dependent-fields-validation) ...if you want to turn this feature off entirely, set it to undefined (validation will be fired **on form submit attempt only**): `<script> ea.settings.dependencyTriggers = undefined; </script>`.

Comment: @jwaliszko that solved my problem, add it as an answer and I'll accept it. I promise it'll be sooner than 8 months too :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've tried using

```
display:block;
```

instead of

```
visibility:visible;
```

in your CSS.